# Vuejs with Codeigniter3 .htaccess setting error

Tags: codeigniter, vue.js

my project structure is

- api   # Codeigniter Root
- css
- img
- js
- index.html  # vuejs Root

I want redirect

/   ->   vujes

/peoples -> vuejs

/contact -> vuejs

/api/user/authorize  -> Codeigniter

my .htaccess code is

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteRule ^(api)($|/) - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

  RewriteBase /api
  RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /api/index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Vuejs vue-router work correctly, but Codeigniter freindly url is not work.
/   ->   vujes (work)

/peoples -> vuejs (work)

/contact -> vuejs (work)

/api/  ->  codeigniter (work)

/api/user/authorize   -> vuejs (not work)

how do i fix?

Answer (score 1):

i find my question myself.

/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?(api)/
  RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ /api/index.php?$1 [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?(api)/
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

/api/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 SetEnv CI_ENV production

 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /api
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /api/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```